# Translation Golf XXXV - The sea of miracles

Tags: translation-golf

> This game has ended, the winner is **VeAqui** with a translation of just [43 characters](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24483/12637)!

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This edition proposed game is to translate [the second chorus of *奇跡の海 (Kiseki no umi)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ux90A4YDLdo&t=123), "The sea of miracles", a Japanese song that served as opening theme for the *Record of Lodoss War* series:

> 風よ 私は立ち向かう
>   行こう 輝きを目指して
>   祈り この胸に抱きしめ
>   彷徨う 闇のような未来
>
> Kaze yo watashi wa tachimukau
>   Yukou kagayaki wo mezashite
>   Inori kono mune ni dakishime
>   Samayou yami no you na mirai

Its English translation goes like this:

> Oh wind, I will stand and face you!
>   I will go and head for the brilliance.
>   Embracing a prayer to my heart,
>   I wander the seemingly dark future.
>
> <sub>(110 characters.)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact. In this case, *the original text* refers to the English tranlation of the Japanese text, as the Japanese text will not be taken into account for the answers.

Here's a (non-golfed) example translation:

> ¡Oh, viento! ¡Me enfrentaré a ti sin caer!
>  Caminando hacia la iluminación,
>  abrazando una oración en mi pecho
>  y errando por el aparentemente oscuro futuro.
>  
>  <sub>(123 characters)</sub>

Note that in this edition the rhyme bonuses will not apply as there are no rhymes in the original text.

---

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 43 Chars

> ¡Brisa, ganaré!
>
> sigo la luz
>
> mi ser ora
>
> iré al mañana ¿mate?

No sé si la brisa y el ¿mate? (con interrogante para indicar que es posible que sea negro) sean válidos, en tal caso toca cambiarlos por ráfaga y opaco... si es que aplican para la traducción

Comment: Entiendo que has buscado un sinónimo de "viento" con menos letras, aunque resulta poco creíble que una brisa pueda llegar a tumbar algo, así la traducción pierde su fuerza. :-D

Comment: @walen puede ser, solo que visto desde un sentido poético no es lo mismo decir que desafías al viento que a la brisa. Queda un desafío un tanto descafeinado. :-D Sobre la nueva versión, necesito que defiendas (argumentes) los dos últimos versos: lo de "colmado en ruego" y lo de "futuro mate". ¿Cómo se corresponde eso con el original? No digo que no sea válido, solo que añadas una explicación.

Comment: pues ante la defensa que me brinda @walen (¡gracias! )y con la mayor de las penas con la *elocuencia poética*... creo que volveré a la brisa (con otros cambios, claro está)

Comment: Buena reducción, pero no le veo sentido a la construcción "iré al sería mate". Estás usando "sería" como sustantivo pero no me suena correcto. ¿Hay ejemplos en la literatura de algo parecido?

Comment: pues más que *sería* iba a usar *será* pero este último implica que el futuro **no** tendrá brillo, el sería lo deja como posible (si no encuentro ejemplos similares, busco de otra forma...)

Comment: Hay algunos casos de verbos que se han sustantivizado: sin ir más lejos podrías usar "porvenir" como sinónimo de "futuro". Pero usar "sería" como sustantivo no lo veo correcto, no le encuentro sentido a la frase. Si no encuentras casos con estructuras similares en la literatura deberás cambiarla.

Answer (score 6):

#### <s>71</s> 44

> ¡[Aire](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1L3KU50#Kc83v59): [opugno](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R7rfFFQ#BaIupeD)!
>   [Excelso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HBfNljn) seré.
>   [Vago](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bFsrlQS), con [fe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HhQFq5H),
>   por [negro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QN0nGts#KSUp7cb) futuro.

Comment: Opugno esta edición! jajaja. No, es broma, queria usar esa palabra

Answer (score 5):

### <s>91</s> 64 caracteres

> ¡Viento, te reto!
> Iré a la luz.
> Acojo un rezo en mí,
> erro por el futuro que tira a negro.